# A question about the "pasting lemma".

Tags: general-topology

The pasting lemma says:

> Let $X=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$. Let $f:A\to Y$ and $g:B\to Y$ be continuous. If $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in A\cap B$, then $f$ and $g$ combine to give a continuous function $h:X\to Y$, defined by setting $h(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in A$ and $h(x)=g(x)$ if $x\in B$.

Let $A=[1,2]$ and $B=[3,4]$. Also, let $f([1,2])=1$ and $f([3,4])=2$. How is $f$ continuous on $[1,2]\cup [3,4]$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f$ is constant on each small enough (diameter less than $1$) neighbourhood of each point, thus $f$ is continuous in each point.

Comment: How is $f$ not continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then we may pick $\delta=1>0$ and verify that for all $x,y\in [1,2]\cup[3,4]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ (and in fact $=0$).